# Rails can't find rake gem for docker app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application running in docker. I have two images which are connected. I can't run server of one of them and it works fine, but I cannot run another one and none of simple commands doesn't work too. It fails telling me Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources.

[There is already existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598686/rails-cant-find-rake-gem)

None of the solutions from link above doesn't work.

### Error looks  like this

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/usr/local/bundle/bin/puma)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
```

### Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
gem 'puma'  
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.21'
gem 'redis-rails'

gem 'json'
gem 'jbuilder'

gem 'omniauth',               '~> 1.8.1'
gem 'omniauth-auth0',         '~> 2.0.0'  
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.5.2'
gem 'omniauth-barong',        '~> 0.1.2'

gem 'figaro'
gem 'hashie', '~> 3.0'

gem 'aasm', '~> 4.12'
gem 'bunny', '~> 2.9.0'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'enumerize'
gem 'datagrid'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'paranoid2'
gem 'active_hash'
gem 'http_accept_language'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'country_select', '~> 2.1.0'

gem 'gon', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'pusher'
gem 'eventmachine', '~> 1.0.4'
gem 'em-websocket', '~> 0.5.1'

gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 4.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'angularjs-rails', '~> 1.3.15'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.2'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'bourbon'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'eco'
gem 'browser', '~> 0.8.0' 
gem 'rbtree'
gem 'liability-proof', '0.0.9'
gem 'grape', '~> 1.0.1' 
gem 'grape-entity', '~> 0.5.2'
gem 'grape-swagger', '~> 0.27.3'
gem 'grape-swagger-ui', '~> 2.2.8'
gem 'rack-attack', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'easy_table'
gem 'faraday', '~> 0.12'
gem 'jwt', '~> 1.5'
gem 'email_validator', '~> 1.6'
gem 'clipboard-rails', '~> 1.7'
gem 'god', '~> 0.13.7', require: false
gem 'mini_racer', '~> 0.1', require: false
gem 'arel-is-blank', '~> 1.0' 
gem 'sentry-raven', '~> 2.7', require: false
gem 'memoist', '~> 0.16'
gem 'method-not-implemented', '~> 1.0'
gem 'passgen', '~> 1.0'
gem 'validates_lengths_from_database', '~> 0.7.0'

group :development, :test do
 gem 'factory_bot_rails'
 gem 'faker', '~> 1.4.3'
 gem 'binding_of_caller'
 gem 'quiet_assets'
 gem 'timecop'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7'
 gem 'pry-byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.7'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'mocha', require: false

 gem 'capybara',            '~> 2.17'
 gem 'selenium-webdriver',  '~> 3.8'
 gem 'chromedriver-helper', '~> 1.1'
 gem 'rack_session_access', '~> 0.1'
 gem 'webmock',             '~> 3.3'
end
```

### Here is Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5.0
MAINTAINER lbellet@heliostech.fr

ARG RAILS_ENV=production
ENV RAILS_ENV ${RAILS_ENV}

ENV APP_HOME=/home/app

RUN groupadd -r app --gid=1000
RUN useradd -r -m -g app -d /home/app --uid=1000 app

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - \
 && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
 && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/source$
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
      default-libmysqlclient-dev \
      imagemagick \
      gsfonts \
      chromedriver \
      nodejs \
      yarn

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock $APP_HOME/

# Install dependencies
RUN mkdir -p /opt/vendor/bundle && chown -R app:app /opt/vendor
RUN su app -s /bin/bash -c "bundle install --path /opt/vendor/bundle"

# Copy the main application.
COPY . $APP_HOME

RUN chown -R app:app /home/app
USER app

RUN ./bin/init_config \
  && chmod +x ./bin/logger \
  && bundle exec rake tmp:create yarn:install assets:precompile

# Expose port 8080 to the Docker host, so we can access it
# from the outside.
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]

# The main command to run when the container starts. Also
# tell the Rails dev server to bind to all interfaces by
# default.
CMD ["puma", "--config", "config/puma.rb"]
```

I tried to reinstall docker, change ruby version, delete Gemfile.lock, but nothing seems to work. How can I resolve that?

Comment: Run ‘gem install rake’ and let me know if it installs. If not, uninstall it first with the command ‘gem uninstall rake’.

Comment: @usamaman Yes, I've already tried ‘gem install rake’ and it installs, but nothing is changing.

Comment: Try this: gem install rake —version=12.3.1

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar situation, this worked for me:

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to update your `rbenv-bundler` from homebrew.

Try:

```
brew upgrade rbenv-bundler
```

Then, try installing the gem.

```
gem install rake -v 12.3.1
```